# Python re.split() to split by char but let char in splited text

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I've got a problem with split function in python; when I try to split text by `{`, the text splits, but the `{` are removed.

Here is an example:

```
s = "My=pet {looks a dog}, but he is=cat"
```

The desired output is:

```
["My","=","pet","{","looks","a","dog","}",",","but","he","is","=","cat"]
```

Comment: You don't mind that the spaces are consumed by the split?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `re.findall` is more easy:

```
re.findall(r'[^\w\s]|\w+', s)
```

Answer (score 0):

The default split() function split by blank space. If you split by a character or string, it will use that string or character as breakpoints and not as items of the array. 
In the example, you can give a blank space between the words and characters.

```
s = "My = pet { looks a dog }, but he is = cat"
ans=s.split()
for item in ans:
  print ans
```

This will display the result you asked.